# Issue installing package (sanitizer) for node to run browserquest

Tags: node.js, npm

I am playing with node and trying to get [Browser quest](http://browserquest.mozilla.org/) to run locally. I have tried to install the required files and I then tried [this code](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs) to install the n manager and upgraded node to the latest version. In the [BrowserQuest git](https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest/blob/master/server/README.md) readme it lists the packages to include and says:

```
npm install -d
```

should work to install them all but this fails, I installed each one by one but cant install [sanitizer](https://npmjs.org/package/sanitizer), I get this error:

```
Error: No compatible version found: sanitizer@'>=1.0.0-0'
```

Current version of node is 0.10.15 (after upgrade, before that it was an earlier 0.10 but cant remember.

Browserquest says it should work from 0.4.7 up

Question: What do I need to do to get sanitizer to install or is there some other issue? I am new to package managers so a simple answer would be nice.

notes:
I'm on mac. node is in my user home directory and I have done other tutorials with it so it is working.
Browser quest is in my home directory and I have been running the npm and n from within the base directory of BrowserQuest.
I downloaded the BrowserQuest files a month or two ago, not sure if they have changed much...

The full error:

```
$ node server/js/main.js
Warning: Native modules not compiled.  XOR performance will be degraded.
Warning: Native modules not compiled.  UTF-8 validation disabled.

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'sanitizer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/(my home)/bq/server/js/utils.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the package manager is looking for versions ">0" but isn't understanding the format "0.0.0".
I edited my **package.json** file to use the format "0.0.0" and it worked like a champ!

FROM THIS:

```
{
"name": "BrowserQuest"
, "version": "0.0.1"
 , "private": false 
 , "dependencies": {
"underscore": ">0"
, "log": ">0"
, "bison": ">0"
, "websocket": ">0"
, "websocket-server": ">0"
, "sanitizer": ">0"
, "memcache": ">0"
 }
}
```

TO THIS:

```
{
"name": "BrowserQuest"
, "version": "0.0.1"
 , "private": false 
 , "dependencies": {
"underscore": ">0.0.0"
, "log": ">0.0.0"
, "bison": ">0.0.0"
, "websocket": ">0.0.0"
, "websocket-server": ">0.0.0"
, "sanitizer": ">0.0.0"
, "memcache": ">0.0.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should read through all the code I guess. still, not sure why it didn't work when I tried to install it directly...

Comment: How did you try to install sanitizer directly? Through npm? What did you do and what happened?

Comment: I just went back through terminal and saw that it was looking at the browserquest info because that is the folder I was in. even though I just typed npm install sanitizer